# Python (Memory Error when appending a list)

Tags: python

I am looking for a way to, probably, modify this function so appending data to a list doesn't produce a Memory Error.

I have a program that reads one file line by line and writes the data from this file to the text file based on some conditions (the file will have more than 1000000 rows). I have functions that append several lists (they are long), and then I write data from the lists to the text file row by row.

If the file reaches max num of lines (1000000), I split it. **It worked fine, however** I needed the function below that appends an additional list (I modified it for this example) and **when I append 0 to the list in the else statement**, it produces a Memory Error.

I am on 64-bit OS, Windows 10 (RAM 16GB) and use Python 2.7 (32-bit) - but splitting the file approach usually works for me w/o updating anything, that is why I wonder if I just could solve the problem by modifying the loop.

Thank you for any suggestions!

```
# This function writes data to the lists based on the given conditions.*

def get_new_list(workbook, list_1, list_2, list_equal_values):


    worksheet1 = workbook.sheet_by_name('SomeWorksheet')

    list_11 = []
    list_22 = []
    list_new_values = []

    # Get data from the worksheet and append to the lists.
    for row in range(1, worksheet1.nrows):
        value_11 = worksheet1.cell(row, 0).value
        value_22 = worksheet1.cell(row, 1).value
        new_value = worksheet1.cell(row, 10).value

        list_11.append(value_11)
        list_22.append(value_22)
        list_new_values.append(new_value)


    # Compare values from list_1, list_2 to values in list_11 and list_22.
    for index in range(len(list_1)):
        for i in range(len(list_11)):
            if str(list_1[index]) == str(list_11[i]) \
               and str(list_2 [index]) == str(list_22[i]):
                 value = list_new_values[i]
                 list_equal_values.insert(index, value)

            elif str(list_1[index]) == str(list_11[i]) \
                  and str(list_2 [index]) != str(list_22[i]):
                          value = list_new_values[i]
                         list_equal_values (index, value)

            **else:
            # He is the problem, Memory Error, but I need to append 0 
            # if the  first two conditions are not met**
                 list_equal_values.append(0)

    return list_equal_values
        # I empty the lists in case the file is split and new data is sent to this     function.
    del list_11[:]
    del list_22[:]
    del list_new_values[:]
```

Comment: Instead of creating `list_11` and `list_22` and then iterating over them to compare with `list_1` and `list_2`, you can just check`list_1` and `list_2` as you iterate over rows of the workbook. This removes two lists in the full population and saves you a lot of memory. With that said, it sounds like you've hit the 4GB limit on a process for RAM.= with 32-bit. You could also work with subprocesses if the above doesn't fit your needs.

Comment: The reason for these two additional lists is that this spreadsheet has some numerical data, and, for example, I need to compare the dates from the two lists that I pass to this function with the dates from these new lists, and if they are equal (or based on the conditions from the for loop), then I append numbers to the new list. Hope I don't complicate my explanations:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not with you for-loops. It's with your arrays growing bigger and bigger. Try to delete all unnecessary arrays or appends, to be more memory-efficient.

If it's not possible, you may try to store partial results in files, but that can be messy.

If you want a simple solution, I remember I had a similar problem time ago. After a looooooot of research, I figured out that if I switched to Python 2.7 (64-bit)... problem solved!

Hope it helps! I remember I spent a lot of time figuring this out, so dont make my same mistakes

Comment: You may be right with the 4gb limitation in 32-bit, but can we address the need for proper use of lists in the code first before "adding more memory allocation"?

Comment: Thank you! I also played around with this for loop, and without iterating through the inner for loop (or just doing for example: for a, b in zip(list_1, list_2), it works - but of course I miss some data because it is always the same combination. But as you said, it can get messy :) Also, last time updating to 64 didn't help me for some reason, but I had way bigger files:) I will try updating it again and thank you for pointing out that you did a research on this - saved me time :)